# Rails HTTP basic authentication across subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, basic-authentication

I've got some really basic authentication for a staging/testing site (this is just to protect the staging site, we use Devise for authentication within the app):

```
authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
  username == "xxx" && password == "xxx"
end
```

It's an app which uses multiple subdomains. The authentication works fine, it pops up a dialog and you enter the credentials and the browser prompts you to save the credentials which I do as I don't want to enter them again every time.

The problem is that every time you navigate to a new subdomain you need to enter them again, not very convenient for testers. Is there any way around this with http basic? Or is there a better way to protect staging sites?

Thanks.